# Google App Engine: Webtest simulating logged in user and administrator

Tags: python, google-app-engine

from the webtest documentation I learn that:

> The best way to simulate
>   authentication is if your application
>   looks in environ['REMOTE_USER'] to see
>   if someone is authenticated. Then you
>   can simply set that value, like:

```
app.get('/secret', extra_environ=dict(REMOTE_USER='bob'))
```

I am trying to do the same thing but in a Google App engine environment. I would like to simulate a logged in user and a user that's an administrator.

If possible which dictionary values do I have to set in extra_environ to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Set User:**

```
os.environ['USER_EMAIL'] = 'info@example.com'
```

**Set Admin:**

```
os.environ['USER_IS_ADMIN'] = '1'
```

This is how my whole test looks like. My example uses webtest, nose, nosegae and gaetestbed.

```
class TestingRoutes(WebTestCase, unittest.TestCase):

    APPLICATION = application()

    def tearDown(self):
        os.environ['USER_EMAIL'] = ''
        os.environ['USER_IS_ADMIN'] = ''

    #AdminIndex .....
    def test_adminindex_no_user(self):
        #No user: redirect to login form
        response = app.get( url_map['adminindex'] )
        self.assertRedirects(response)

    def test_adminindex_user(self):      
        os.environ['USER_EMAIL'] = 'info@example.com'
        response = app.get( url_map['adminindex'] )
        self.assertForbidden(response)

    def test_adminindex_admin(self):
        os.environ['USER_EMAIL'] = 'info@example.com'
        os.environ['USER_IS_ADMIN'] = '1'
        response = app.get( url_map['adminindex'] )
        self.assertOK(response)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  The code acts as if no one is logged in, although I set os.environ['USER_EMAIL'] = 'info@example.com'.  Might be my error, but it's not obvious how to debug.